# Parameter is an undeclared type?

Tags: ios, swift, function, parameters

I'm trying to set a parameter for a function but the console is stating

> Use of undeclared type `rightAnimation`

```
func slideFromRight(from: rightInAnimation.fromValue = 25) {

    let rightInAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    rightInAnimation.duration = 0.5
    rightInAnimation.fromValue = 25
    rightInAnimation.toValue = 0
    rightInAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    self.layer.add(rightInAnimation, forKey: "animateTranslation")
}
```

I'm confused. I thought I wouldn't have to declare this at top level. The intention is to be able to change the `fromValue` when assigning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the following code:

```
func slideFromRight(from: rightInAnimation.fromValue = 25)
```

You need to change that to:

```
func slideFromRight(from : Int = 25)
{
    let rightInAnimation            = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    rightInAnimation.duration       = 0.5
    rightInAnimation.fromValue      = from
    rightInAnimation.toValue        = 0
    rightInAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

    self.layer.add(rightInAnimation, forKey: "animateTranslation")
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. Such a simple solution